# How to limit the domains that can call my page/web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm having a web service witch I want to use on several domains. However, I want to limit the sites (domains) that can access my web service.

For example, I want a request made by a page in site www.Site-A.com will execute and a request from www.Site-B.com to deny.

Is there a way to do it with ASP.NET / IIS?

Comment: Are you talking about wider DNS domains or windows security domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you have a web content that may be referenced by other pages outside of your domain.  Those pages will have been loaded into a browser then requests from references in those pages will attempt to get content from your site.  Does that describe your scenario?

If so then the only chance you have to acheive this is to require that the requests be delivered with a `referer` header (which is normal but some browsers allow the user to suppress it).  You can then examine the content of the `referer` header in your code to test whether you want to continue with the request.

You can examine the `referer` with this code:-

```
 var referer = new Uri(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"));
 if (referer.Host.ToLower() == "www.site-a.com")
    //Allow access
```

**Caveat**

This technique can only be used informally, there is no way to authenticate the `referer` header so anyone can spoof it using fairly simple tools.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. For my need, this will help. This is the place to tell you I saw your answers on several issues and enjoyed!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the IP address of the remote user and act accordingly. You can use the `Referer` header of the request, too, but that can be spoofed.

Comment: I can have the IP address - but the issue is the site he is using and not the user IP. I edited my question to explain it. Thank you!

Comment: If that's the case, can't you just look the domain up from some whois provider? :)